# Handle POST data sent as array

Tags: perl, cgi

I have an html form which sends a hidden field and a radio button with the same name.

This allows people to submit the form without picking from the list (but records a zero answer).

When the user *does* select a radio button, the form posts BOTH the hidden value and the selected value.

I'd like to write a perl function to convert the POST data to a hash. The following works for standard text boxes etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
sub GetForm{
    %form;
    foreach my $p (param()) {
         $form{$p} = param($p); 
    }
    return %form;
}
```

However when faced with two form inputs with the same name it just returns the first one (ie the hidden one)

I can see that the inputs are included in the POST header as an array but I don't know how to process them.

I'm working with legacy code so I can't change the form unfortunately!

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an html form which sends a hidden field and a radio button with
>   the same name.
>
> This allows people to submit the form without picking from the list
>   (but records a zero answer).

That's an odd approach. It would be easier to leave the hidden input out and treat the absence of the data as a zero answer.

---

However, if you want to stick to your approach, read the documentation for [the CGI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod).

Specifically, the [documentation for param](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter):

> When calling param() If the parameter is multivalued (e.g. from multiple selections in a scrolling list), you can ask to receive an array. Otherwise the method will return the first value.

Thus:

```
$form{$p} = [ param($p) ];
```

---

However, you do seem to be reinventing the wheel. There is a [built-in method to get a hash of all paramaters](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-parameter-list-as-a-hash):

```
$form = $CGI->new->Vars
```

---

That said, the documentation also says:

> CGI.pm is no longer considered good practice for developing web applications, including quick prototyping and small web scripts. There are far better, cleaner, quicker, easier, safer, more scalable, more extensible, more modern alternatives available at this point in time. These will be documented with [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

So you should migrate away from this anyway.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. I'm pulling apart someone's code from 2004 who seems to have been trained in the 1950's.  This is very hacky but I went with : if([param($p)]->[1]){
      $dataToReturn{$p} = [param($p)]->[1];
  }else{
      $dataToReturn{$p} = [param($p)]->[0];
  }

Comment: Note that using `param` in list context is deprecated, and you should use `multi_param` for this instead, to make it clear that you want a list. This attempts to avoid the case where it is accidentally used in a list context.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$form{$p} = param($p);                             # Value of first field named $p
```

with

```
$form{$p} = ( multi_param($p) )[-1];               # Value of last field named $p
```

or

```
$form{$p} = ( grep length, multi_param($p) )[-1];  # Value of last field named $p
                                                   # that has a non-blank value
```